# Count the total number of sharing in ios app

Tags: ios, mysql, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I'm developing an application, and in the main form of this application i coded 3 button: Facebook share,Twitter Share and Email sharing.

The main question is that when each user share the application the database (MYSQL) will be update to count how many times people have shared this application. However I will be using an NS timer to check the count from the database every 3s.

Is this process will cause any trouble for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the work is done on a background thread is fine, just don't block the UI.

Comment: so you mean that the count check i do it in the background? or better to start it when the user open the application

Comment: Yes, do the work in background and if you need to update some UI element do that on main thread.